# Error using SimpleImputer and OrdinalEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to practice a simple exercise in imputing categorical variables. I'm aware that SimpleImputer works directly on categorical variables, but I'm just doing an exercise for myself. I'm having a very strange error with the final line of this code.

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
df=pd.DataFrame({"cat":["S","M","L","M","S","S",np.nan]})
encoder=OrdinalEncoder(); imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")
df["encoded"]=encoder.fit_transform(df[["cat"]])
df["encoded_imp"]=imputer.fit_transform(df[["encoded"]])

#This final line is not working
df["encoded_cat"]=encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]])
```

The final line above is not working.

The error is (Please note that my Python installation is installed by/within Julia):

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 9
      6 df["encoded"]=encoder.fit_transform(df[["cat"]])
      7 df["encoded_imp"]=imputer.fit_transform(df[["encoded"]])
----> 9 df["encoded_cat"]=encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]])

File ~\.julia\conda\3\x86_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4091, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   4088     self._setitem_array([key], value)
   4089 else:
   4090     # set column
-> 4091     self._set_item(key, value)

File ~\.julia\conda\3\x86_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4300, in DataFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   4290 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   4291     """
   4292     Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
   4293 
   (...)
   4298     ensure homogeneity.
   4299     """
-> 4300     value, refs = self._sanitize_column(value)
   4302     if (
   4303         key in self.columns
   4304         and value.ndim == 1
   4305         and not isinstance(value.dtype, ExtensionDtype)
   4306     ):
   4307         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
   4308         if not self.columns.is_unique or isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):

File ~\.julia\conda\3\x86_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:5040, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   5038 if is_list_like(value):
   5039     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
-> 5040 return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True), None

File ~\.julia\conda\3\x86_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py:608, in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, allow_2d)
    606 subarr = data
    607 if data.dtype == object:
--> 608     subarr = maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(data)
    609     if (
    610         object_index
    611         and using_pyarrow_string_dtype()
    612         and is_string_dtype(subarr)
    613     ):
    614         # Avoid inference when string option is set
    615         subarr = data

File ~\.julia\conda\3\x86_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:1172, in maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(value)
   1169     raise TypeError(type(value))  # pragma: no cover
   1170 if value.ndim != 1:
   1171     # Caller is responsible
-> 1172     raise ValueError(value.ndim)  # pragma: no cover
   1174 if not len(value):
   1175     return value

ValueError: 2
```

EDIT: I can fix this with

`df["encoded_cat"]=encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]]).flatten()` but I'm still curious why the original error.

Comment: What version your `sklearn`?

Comment: It's version 1.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a certain shape to the right hand side, you need the same shape to the left hand side if your values have dtype `object`.

```
# shape=(7, ) vs shape=(7, 1) => it doesn't work
df["encoded_cat"] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]])

# shape=(7, 1) vs shape=(7, 1) => it works
df[["encoded_cat"]] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]])
# df[["encoded_cat"]] = encoder.inverse_transform(np.expand_dims(df["encoded_imp"], 1))

# shape=(7, ) vs shape=(7, ) => it works
df["encoded_cat"] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]]).flatten
# df["encoded_cat"] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]]).squeeze()
```

So you need to expand the dimension for `encode.inverse_transform` works then reduce the dimension to fit to your column. There are many function to numpy to manipulate the dimensions: np.hstack, np.vstack, np.newaxis (broadcasting), np.expand_dims, np.squeeze, etc.

It works if you force a *"fixed"* dtype:

```
df["encoded_cat"] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]]).astype(str)
```

Comment: I thought about shape, but I don't think that's the cause. The other lines of code handle the reshaping just fine. For example, the following works fine:

`A=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]).reshape(7,1);  df["test"]=A`

Pandas is smart enough to reshape A, which is (7,1), to be a new column of df.

Comment: It's because you have a numeric dtype not an object and Pandas can infer it. In your case, you can do `df["encoded_cat"] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]]).astype(str)`. I updated my answer according your excellent comment.

Comment: Ah I see. `A=np.array(['a','bbb','cc','d','e','f','g']).reshape(7,1); df["test"]=A` also works fine, but printing A clearly identifies its dtype as '<U3', whereas `encoder.inverse_transform(df[["encoded_imp"]])` has dtype object. In that case, I think this error message is very uninformative! Thank you very much.